# GCP and TPU, experimental_connect_to_cluster give no response

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I am  trying to use TPU on GCP with tensorflow 2.1 with Keras API.
Unfortunately, I am stuck after creating the tpu-node.
In fact, it seems that my VM "see" the tpu, but could not connect to it.

The code I am using :

```
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_name)
print('Running on TPU ', resolver.master())
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

The code is stuck line 3, I received few messages and then nothing, so I do not know what could be the issue. Therefore I am suspecting some connection's issue between the VM and the TPU.

The message :

> 2020-04-22 15:46:25.383775: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use:
>   SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA 2020-04-22 15:46:25.992977: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency:
>   2300000000 Hz 2020-04-22 15:46:26.042269: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service
>   0x5636e4947610 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee
>   that XLA will be used). Devices: 2020-04-22 15:46:26.042403: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor
>   device (0): Host, Default Version 2020-04-22 15:46:26.080879: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:147] Creating new
>   thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using
>   inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance. E0422
>   15:46:26.263937297    2263 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:198] check for
>   SO_REUSEPORT:
>   {"created":"@1587570386.263923266","description":"SO_REUSEPORT
>   unavailable on compiling
>   system","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":166}
>   2020-04-22 15:46:26.269134: I
>   tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:300]
>   Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> 10.163.38.90:8470}
>   2020-04-22 15:46:26.269192: I
>   tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:300]
>   Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job localhost -> {0 ->
>   localhost:32263}

Moreover, I am using the "Deep Learning" Image from gcp, so I should not need to install anything, right ?

Does anyone have the same issue with TF 2.1 ?
P.S : the same code works fine on Kaggle and Colab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to reproduce, I used `ctpu up --zone=europe-west4-a --disk-size-gb=50 --machine-type=n1-standard-8 --tf-version=2.1` to create vm and tpu. Then ran your code, and it succeeded.

```
taylanbil@taylanbil:~$ python3 run.py 
Running on TPU  grpc://10.240.1.2:8470
2020-04-28 19:18:32.597556: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2020-04-28 19:18:32.627669: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2000189999 Hz
2020-04-28 19:18:32.630719: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x471b980 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-28 19:18:32.630759: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-04-28 19:18:32.665388: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:300] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> 10.240.1.2:8470}
2020-04-28 19:18:32.665439: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:300] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job localhost -> {0 -> localhost:33355}
2020-04-28 19:18:32.683216: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:300] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> 10.240.1.2:8470}
2020-04-28 19:18:32.683268: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:300] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job localhost -> {0 -> localhost:33355}
2020-04-28 19:18:32.690405: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:390] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:33355
taylanbil@taylanbil:~$ cat run.py 
import tensorflow as tf
TPU_name='taylanbil'
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_name)
print('Running on TPU ', resolver.master())
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

How do you create your tpu resources? Can you double check if there is no version mismatch?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. It seems my issue probably comes from the subnetwork I am using when I created the VM. It has some firewall rules which does not allow the communication with the TPU I think. I need to wait the update of the firewall rule (I do not have the permission to do that where I am working)

Comment: Ok, makes sense. In that case, if you need further assistance, I suggest that you file a bug via the google cloud ui.

Comment: @Shiro can you provide more detail on how to solve the subnetwork problem ? I'm having similar issue, building the TPU+VM with `ctpu up` does not help, and creating a firewall rule allowing everything does not work either...

Comment: @Astariul Hi, are you using a subnetwork when creating your VM ? if it is the case, the easiest way is to create a vm without subnetwork, then you should not have any issue to connect to the TPU

Comment: @Shiro thanks for the fast answer ! I'm not aware using any subnetwork. My command is : `ctpu up --zone=europe-west4-a --disk-size-gb=50 --machine-type=n1-standard-2 --tf-version2.2 --tpu-size v3-8 --name mytpu`

Comment: @Astariul I have never used the command line, until now I was using just the UI. But from what I understand you are creating a VM with TF preinstalled and link a TPU. So there should not be any issue.
Can you double check if the ip adress and the port of the TPU is not misspelled in your python script ?

Comment: @Shiro thanks for your help. I double-checked and the TPU IP is fine. I can see the TPU from the VM using `nmap -Pn -p8470 TPUIP`, but I simply cannot connect to it...

Comment: Can you just show a little piece of your script just in case because I do not understand why it is not working, it seems very strange

Answer (score 1):

I created my VM + TPU with `ctpu up --zone=europe-west4-a --disk-size-gb=50 --machine-type=n1-standard-2 --tf-version=2.2 --tpu-size v3-8 --name cola-tpu`

But still I couldn't access the TPU, it hanged like OP described.

I opened a Google issue and got the answer there :

> This is a known issue that occurs some times and the product team is
> currently trying to fix it.
>
> While that happens, let me propose some troubleshooting steps:
>
> 1- Disable and then reenable TPU API
>
> If this does not work:
>
> 2.1- Go to VPC network > VPC network peering
>
> 2.2- Check if `cp-to-tp-peeringdefault[somenumbers]` has `inactive` status.
>
> 2.3- If it does, delete it and create a tpu node again
>
> Please let us know if any of this worked for you so that we can close
> this ticket (in case it did) or keep with providing support (in case
> it did not).

For me, deleting `cp-to-tp-peeringdefault` and recreating VM + TPU worked.